double taxation when more than two countries are involved
I am a US citizen living in Spain with a bank account in India as well that earns interest. Conceptually, I understand avoiding double taxation when two countries are involved. But, how does it work with more than two countries?
Tax gets deducted by my bank at source from the interest earned in India and the Indian tax agency is paid. On my Spanish tax form I declare the interest earned (and tax paid) in India, and pay any difference to the Spanish Hacienda. But then, I do the same for the US IRS. So, effectively, I have been taxed three times on my Indian interest. Does that sound correct? Or, am I interpreting something incorrectly here?


So, effectively, I have been taxed three times on my Indian interest. Does that sound correct?

Yes.
Tax treaties are usually bilateral. There may be a Spanish-US tax treaty, Indo-US tax treaty, and a Spanish-Indian tax treaty, and they will all affect you.
Absent treaties, you'll pay taxes where income is sourced by the sourcing rules of the countries involved.
Unless for some reason you're considered a resident in India, you're a tax resident of two countries - the US (by virtue of your citizenship) and Spain (by virtue of your living there). As such both have a claim on all of your income, and the treaty between them determines who taxes what and how.
The US usually taxes its citizens without any regard to treaties ("savings clause", excluding some very specific items), and instead uses the foreign tax credit and the foreign earned income exclusion to mitigate double taxation. An example of specific items not excluded for citizens is usually social security (check the US-Spanish treaty for details).
You'll need to check the Spanish rules and the Indian rules on foreign tax credits, avoiding double taxation, and sourcing rules for interest income for non residents. You'll need to read and understand all the relevant treaties and how they interact with each other.
I suggest hiring a professional if significant amounts are involved.

thanks for a very helpful answer. One doubt remains. You say that "An example of specific items not excluded for citizens is usually social security (check the US-Spanish treaty for details)." I am not sure what you mean by not excluded. I believe there is a Totalization Agreement that allows paying Social Security tax to only one country and not both.

@punkish I'm talking about taxation of the income from social security, not the social security tax which is a different thing

This is a peculiar situation involving 3 countries. Taxation as follows:

India - Taxable. TDS deductible at 31.2%
Spain - Taxable as per resident provisions (no idea of Spain Tax law)
US - Taxable on citizenship basis.

You can pay tax in India (understand that it is already deducted). In Spain & US, you need to check foreign tax provisions & claim a relief in each country's tax return on India tax. This is what I can think of from the facts provided. If amount is significant, consult a CA.
